# How do I close a Browser tab opened earlier in within an angular session?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to close a Browser tab (Chrome but shouldnt matter) opened somewhere in the session but before the user exits the session. This needs to be done at the very end when the cleanup guards run for the `/user -> /` route which we use to service the user.

I tried initially to do this `onDestroy` of the component where the tab is first created. however, this isnt correct since the user could navigate to other components and return back to this causing `onDestroy` to fire closing the tab prematurely in the session

Looking to see if this can be done in a Guard or equivalent where I can get a handle to a tab opened earlier in the session?

Really looking to answer these questions:

- Is there a way to get a handle to the tab (or any tab) by name in Guards and thus is this acceptable way to close tabs opened in the session?

Comment: What's a tab ? A browser tab ?

Comment: yes. updated the heading

Comment: The [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) might work but I havent tried it so let me knw

Comment: thanks  -but isnt there a simpler way to get a handle to the WindowToken object using named search (ie name of the Tab which I do know?) within Guards?

Comment: I don't think so. Browsers are very secured when it comes to JS and they prevent any tab communication. The broadcast is the only method I'm aware of to do that.

Comment: how about storing the original WindowToken object we used to create the tab in the first place - in a local store and retrieving it and then closing it ? I havent every tried something like this but dont want to attempt this if its not feasible?

Comment: I don't know what a WindowToken is, I have never used it. Try and see what happens, and let me know !